# Управление сборщиком мусора

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые ХэшКодовцы. В программе, которую мне необходимо написать, требуется создавать более миллиона экземпляров одного класса за минимальный промежуток времени. Естественно, никакого объема оперативы для этого не хватит. Напрашивается вопрос: как управлять сборщиком мусора? Мне его необходимо вызывать в опр. участках кода. Буду рад любым ссылкам(не на поисковые системы, а на проверенные Вами статьи) и Вашим ответам.

**Заранее спасибо.**

*З.Ы.: Код должен быть управляемым, только C#

З.Ы.2: Программа с подобным кол. экземпляров, по определению есть не оптимальной. Дело в том, что именно такие условия задания. Именно поэтому прошу альтернативные решения не рассматривать.

З.Ы.3: Приветствуются любые рекомендации и советы насчет того, как избежать переполнения стека.

З.Ы.4: Приветствуются любые ссылки относительно работы с большими числами.*

Comment: [GC - класс](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.gc.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда то тоже нужно было подобное на одном из форумов мне так ответили:

> Количество памяти определяется полями объекта и полями его предков. Плюс для каждого объекта CLR создает дополнительно 2 поля: Type object pointer и Sync block index. В книге Рихтера (CLR via C#) подробно описано создание экземпляров класса.
> Принудительно уничножить объект нельзя. Но есть возможность освободить ресурсы занимаемые объектом - паттерн Dispose.

Если в Вашем классе используются свойства, то можете попробовать методику отложенной инициализации, при этой методике некоторые члены класса не инициализируются, пока не потребуется. Подробнее [тут](http://www.coding4.net/post/additional-possibilities-of-properties-usage-in-C.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

а при чем тут сборщик мусора?

- он по определению неуправляемый
- зачем вам его вызывать?
- все зависит от размера экземпляра, если миллион их поместится в размер процесса разрешенный в системе, то никаких проблем с созданием не возникнет, даже если не хватит оперативы, ну будет думать минут надцать, посвопит сильно, размерность времени исполнения не ваша забота
- в условие задачи не входит хранение экземпляра, удаляйте его сразу после создания :)

Comment: Почитайте про различия management и  unmanagement кода в .NET

Comment: В C# нету возможности получать прямой доступ к памяти, поэтому нету аналога C++ операторa delete. Этим занимается сборщик мусора, именно поэтмоу он не нужен. Управлять сборщиком мусора можно, но код при этом будет небезопасный, что по-заданию не положено. Меня интересует именно то, что выше указал юзер nbit. Спасибо ему.

Comment: Если попытаться создавать такое кол. объектов, то просто-напросто выскочит stack overflow. Нужно подойти по-другому.

Comment: Скорее OutOfMemoryException, да и не по причине нехватки памяти, а из-за отсутствия места в адресном пространстве.